# How do I select a range of div classes with different numbers?

Tags: jquery, hide

I'm trying to hide elements with a similar name but different numbers at the end. How can I do this without typing each one seperately using Jquery?

```
$(".switch1, .switch2, .switch3, switch4, .switch5, etc...").hide();
```

Comment: please provide some example

Comment: See [Attribute Starts With Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

Comment: So instead of the code above I want something that says : hide all classes containing '.switch'.

Comment: So put the `switch` class on all those elements and call `$('.switch').hide()`. Much easier, more reliable and extensible.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this, like:

```
function getIndexedClasses(name, indexes) {
    return "(" + indexes.map((i) => `.${name}${i}`).join(", ") + ")";
}
```

and use it like:

```
$(getIndexedClasses("switch", [1, 2, 3, 5])).hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery attribute selector in one shot.

```js
$( "div[class*='switch']" ).text( "Switchclass" );

for(var i=1;i<4;i++){
   var classname='switch'+i;
   $( "div[class*='"+classname+"']" ).css({"color":"red"} );
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>attributeStartsWith demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class='switch1'></div>
 <div class='switch2'></div>
 <div class='switch3'></div>
 <div class='switch4'></div>
 <div class='someother'>Hello</div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What if I want to select a range like switch 1-3?